# fetch HTML with Java - some characters not fetched correctly

Tags: java, html, html-parsing

I need to fetch HTML from Turkish webpages using Java. However, I am finding that my Java code is not able to pick up certain Turkish characters. Here is the Java code I am using:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;

public class fetchHTML {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    URL urls = new URL("http://www.parkbravo.com.tr/pantolon.php");
    InputStream is = urls.openStream();  
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));

    String line;

    while ((line = dis.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
}
```

The first few lines of output of this code are:

```
ï»¿<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" />
<html lang="tr" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
<title>ParkBravo - ÃrÃ¼nler - Pantolonlar</title>
```

You can see that the title is incorrect: ÃrÃ¼nler should be Ürünler

If I use the following Python code to get the HTML:

```
import urllib2

url = 'http://www.parkbravo.com.tr/pantolon.php' 

usock = urllib2.urlopen(url)
data = usock.read()
usock.close()

print data
```

then the output is correct. Title comes out as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" />
<html lang="tr" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
<title>ParkBravo - Ürünler - Pantolonlar</title>
```

But I want to be able to get the HTML with Java. Does anyone know how I can get this working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`readLine()` in `DataInputStream` is Deprecated. You should use a Reader, which handles the conversion from bytes to characters correctly.

If you use `InputStreamReader`, you can specify the encoding in the constructor and if you wrap it in `BufferedReader`, you can read lines.

Instead of

```
 DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));
```

you can have

```
 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"))
```

Where "UTF-8" can be replaced by whatever encoding you need.

Answer (score 2):

To pick up certain Turkish characters, use encoding "UTF8" that is given as a parameter to an `InputStreamReader` object. And you should use BufferedReader as Jakub Zaverka suggested in his answer. Fully working version of your code:

```
public static void main ( String [] args ) throws Exception
{
    URL url = new URL( "http://www.parkbravo.com.tr/pantolon.php" );
    InputStream is = url.openStream();
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( is, "UTF8" ) );
    String line = "";

    while ( ( line = r.readLine() ) != null )
        System.out.println( line );
}
```